# Is there a way to make my bot embed images if user input an image URL or attached image on description?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made an embed command where my bot will ask what's the title of the embed, description of the embed and what channel the user wants the embed to be sent. It works well, but whenever someone input an image URL link on the description my bot just shows the link not the image.

[image]

I tried using `embed.set_image` it was working

[image]

but whenever a user sends a none link description I get an error

```
Invalid Form Body
In embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.
```

And also when the user replied an attached image the bot will send the embed, but will completely leave the description blank.

[image]

Code that I used for the description.

```
desc= []
await ctx.channel.send('Description that you want to be embed')
                msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author))
                desc.append(msg.content)

desc1 = ''.join(desc)
embed = discord.Embed(color=0xD5A6BD, description=str(desc1),
                                  timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
   await submit_chan.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: Hi, I edited my post with the code I used for the description in the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to indicate an invalid URL. Here's a way to fetch an image url from input/attachment.

```
@commands.command()
async def em(self, ctx, url=None):
  if not url:
    url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
  print(url)
  await ctx.send(embed=Embed().set_image(url=url))
```

Comment: I tried it but I still get an URL error... url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Have you tried 1) giving url with command, 2) attaching a image file with command

Comment: I added my code in the question if that helps. The bot will ask what description do you want to be embed but whenever it’s an image URL link, it doesn’t show the image just the link.

Comment: Your `desc1 ` is set as the `description`, you need to use `set_image` to set url for image.

Comment: Yup! If I do embed.set_image = (name= desc1) it wouldn't accept the message unless it's an image url.